# AWS is charging me but the Billing Console doesn't show what the issue is

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS is charging me but the cost reports aren't showing enough detail to figure out why. I think it might be one EC2 instance I created for the tutorial but I can't figure out how to delete it. Can you help?

I signed up for Amazon free tier and I'm doing the tutorial on https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/?e=gs&p=gsrc
It says on the first page "Many of the services used are included in the AWS Free Tier. For those that are not, the sample application will cost, in total, less than $1/day."  So then I finished the first two modules of that tutorial and quit for the day -- I didn't shut down any services (cause the tutorial didn't tell me to) but today I got an email saying I've exceeded my $5 AWS threshold in only e days! The email has a link to a Cost Report that says it's spending $2.16 per day, but it won't tell me what!
   I've gone through all the cost explorer reports and they confirm I'm spending money on EC2 but I can't find why. Can you help?

Here's a screenshot of the "Billing Management Console" -- says I spent that money on "EC2". But then when I drilled down into EC2 it wouldn't tell me exactly what.
[image]

So I clicked on the AWS Cost Management report and it says I'm spending $2.16 a day but it won't give any more granularity that that because all the advanced reports are monthly and don't yet show the last three days. (Apparently it lets you opt-in to daily/hourly reports but it says it charges a fee for that too so I didn't). So I don't know what specifically is charging. 
[image]

So I clicked on the EC2 Dashboard. It said I'm using one volumne, 2 elastic ip addresses, and 4 security groups. I figured out how to delete the volume but I can't figure out how to delete the IP address or the security group. Are those charging me money? How do I delete them? 
[image]

I went to the EC2 Instances and there is one "Volume" in use (basically a docker container created for the tutorial) so I deleted that, but that was well below what the Free Tier provides, so was that the source of my charges? Then I went to the Instances and it says there is one instance so I deleted that too. But it still says I have two IP addresses and comments below say I'm being charged for that.

How can I delete this IP addresses? There is no delete button.
[image]

How can I be 100% sure everything is deleted and I'm not getting any more charges?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer was actually a NAT Gateway VPN. That doesn't show up on the billing report screenshots above, but I eventually found it mentioned on the billing and then shut it off.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Elastic IP assigned, and it's not in use, AWS charges you for it, if it's actually assigned to an EC2 instance and used, it's free.  (To discourage people from hoarding Elastic IPs.)

When you're in the EC2 web console, click 'Running Instances'.  What do you see?  How many instances?  How many stopped?  How many running?

I don't think the security groups can be deleted, and I don't think AWS charges for them.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I delete those IP addresses? I added a screenshot above of my ips but there is no delete button

Comment: As mentioned in another answer, Elastic IPs are not deleted, but released.

Answer (score 0):

Unassigned ElasticIP will cost you money.

You delete ElasticIPs by **Releasing** them.

Security groups does not cost money. In general, for advanced users it is better to create all resources with CloudFormation stack so they can be all cleaned by deleting the stack.